# AWS Auto Scale Alarm Trigger Failure

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, autoscaling

Have configured an auto scaling group and a launch configuration that will use a scaling policy bound to a target group metric (RequestCountPerTarget, specifically).

However, it is failing to trigger the scaling event.

**Auto Scaling Group**

- The auto scaling group is configured with a proper and existing launch configuration, where there is not an active limit on instances.
- The maximum instance count is higher than the desired count.
- The "Activity History" tab shows zero events fired.

[image: Auto Scaling Group Configuration]

[image: Auto Scaling Policy]

**CloudWatch Alarm**

- Creation of the auto scaling group and scaling policy did create an automatic alarm.
- The alarm did update state to `ALARM`, and trigger an automatic action.

*Automatic Alarm Trigger Action*

```
{
  "error": null,
  "actionState": "Succeeded",
  "notificationResource": "arn:aws:autoscaling:ap-southeast-1:0000:scalingPolicy:0000:autoScalingGroupName/WebScalingGroupV1:policyName/Scale API Requests",
  "stateUpdateTimestamp": 1519937155623,
  "publishedMessage": null
}
```

[image: Automatically Created CloudWatch Alarm]

I have completely removed this group and configuration to recreate it -- as initially, I had spaces in the configuration and scaling group name; I am having the same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with Manu, whom is an AWS support engineer, it was determined that the root cause preventing auto scaling actions to trigger was due to a configuration conflict whereby the `Minimum` and `Desired` instances were set to zero.

Amazon auto scaling groups will **NOT** trigger based on target tracking when the current capacity (`Desired`) is at zero, and apparently will also not give any clear indication of the fault via an error log.

Reference *Target Tracking Considerations* at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-target-tracking.html#target-tracking-considerations

> A target tracking scaling policy does not scale your Auto Scaling group when its current capacity is 0, because target tracking scales proportionally to the current capacity.